# Is it possible to use filters in TreeTable (PrimeFaces)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I know, that it's possible to use filters with columns in a `p:dataTable`:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf

But is it possible to use filters in `p:treeTable` columns?
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableCheckbox.jsf

There's my welcome.xhtml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h2="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>APP</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:treeTable id="treeTable"
                     value="#{treeCheckBox.root}" var="manager"
                     selection="#{treeCheckBox.selectedNodes}" selectionMode="checkbox">

            <p:column style="width:150px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    ID
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{manager.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:100px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Description
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{manager.description}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:100px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    KnowledgeDate
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{manager.knowledgeDate}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: As of now PrimeFaces treeTable does not support for filters, they have recently added sorting feature in treeTable. Become a PrimeFaces PRO user might help you out